Kufr/shirk in Games
As selamu Aleykum Brothers and Sisters,
I have hard waswasa when i Play Videogames which contains false religions or false gods as example the Greek ones. I have read a lot about it that playing such games is not kufr as long as you don't believe in this falsehood. I still have waswasa that I could have done kufr when I play. I generally have waswasa about kufr. I know that playing these games are sinful but If I could prefer I would like to live with a sin and not with kufr al Akbar like any of us. So what can I do against these thoughts I keep repeating la illaha il Allah when I see something shirk.

The best tool to make was-was disappear is to ignore these thoughts. This is a very good tool. Just ignore these thoughts and everything will be fine In Shaa Allah
